# WildFly 11: safe session passivation for development?

Tags: session, jboss, undertow, jboss-wildfly-11

When doing redeploys of some webapp too fast, WildFly 11 loses http session data. I followed http://blog.chris-ritchie.com/2014/07/save-session-state-between-redeploys.html to enable session persistence and it generally works.

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This works: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/266186 ie. adding `<distributable>` to web.xml. That will store sessions in infinispan, and because I'm running a standalone server during development, the session data gets stored to disk on server restarts.